# Missing keyword from CREATE VIEW

Tags: sql, oracle

The question for the section is: 
Create a view called TITLE_UNAVAIL to show the movie titles and media_id of the media not returned yet. The view should not allow any DML operations.

This is for Oracle SQL. The columns are in 2 separate tables which is why I used a JOIN but every time I run the code, I keep receiving an ORA-00905:missing keyword error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_title_unavail
  ("Title", "ID")
AS SELECT m.title, h.media_id
  FROM m_movies m JOIN m_rental_history h
  WHERE m.title IS NULL
WITH READ ONLY;
```

Comment: what/where is your join condition?

Comment: You need a "on" like "on m.id = h.id".

Comment: There is no common column between the 2 tables. I just realized my WHERE clause should be h.return_date IS NULL but that still does not resolve the problem.

Comment: CROSS JOIN has no ON. But that makes no sense here...

Comment: I would be rather surprised if a missing title in the movies table indicated that a rental had not been returned.

Comment: Not related to your question, but - get rid of double quotes around column names. They will make your life miserable from the moment you create the view onwards.

Comment: Please share with us a list of all the columns in m_movies and in m_rental_history (with their types and lengths).  We may be able to advise you which column(s) are the common ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the JOIN keyword, then you need to specify the join condition via the ON keyword. You will need an on condition, or, if you want a Descartes multiplication, then just put the tables into the from clause with comma between them.

Comment: Yes removing the JOIN and using a comma between the 2 tables in the FROM clause seems to have worked. Thank you!